# Google script Alert difficulty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a very basic question related to Google Scripts. I have a small script which allows the user to upload a file to Drive. This works ok.
However, I then want to pop up an alert to say "Thank you",and this is foxing me.

What I have now, in th Post function of the script is:

```
function doPost(e) {

    firstName = e.parameter.firstName;
    lastName = e.parameter.lastName;
    name = lastName+"-"+firstName;
    nameLength = name.length;
    if (nameLength ==1) {
        } 
    else {
        fileName = e.parameter.thefile.name;
        var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
        fileNameLength = fileName.length;
        if(fileNameLength !=0) {
            var fileDocName = e.parameter.assignment+"-"+name+"-"+e.parameter.thefile.name;
            var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob); 
            doc.rename(fileDocName);
            // get assignment folder
            var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
            doc.addToFolder(folder);

            var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
            var ui = app.getUi();
            var response = ui.alert('Assignment uploaded');

      }
  }

  return;
}
```

As I say, this seem to work fine, until the last bit when the execution transcript says things like GetUI not defined and so on, depending exactly how I code it.
I'm quite new to Google scripts so I'm probably missing something obvious. But what?

Answer (score 0):

In short, UiApp doesn't give you something that you can call `alert` on.

I think UiApp.getActiveApplication is intended for if you wanted to change the user interface in some way, e.g. add a button.

It's possible to call alert on SpreadsheetApp and DocumentApp, but not from DriveApp.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.alert('Hello');
```

Finally, it's possible to use the following, which isn't related to any particular Google app, so probably more useful for you,

```
Browser.msgBox('Assignment uploaded');
```

Comment: `Browser.msgBox('Assignment uploaded');` won't work if this script is not bounded to a SS ... in a webapp for example. And the question doesn't mention how the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the UiApp instance to add a message.

```
  ...
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('Thanks'));// or Label or textBox or any other widget
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I know it's too late. `UiApp API` and `UiInstance API` is deprecated. Another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296760/replacement-for-deprecated-uiapp-and-uiinstance/47318103#47318103

Answer (score 0):

There is no UI so you have to respond with an HTML page... If you want an alert() then something like this:

```
doPost(e){
  // ...
  // your 'thank you' assuming web app...
  var response = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    '<html><body onload="alert("Thank you")"></body></html>'
  )

  // ...
  return response
}
```