# replacement for deprecated UiApp and UiInstance

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

To start off I would like to say I am nowhere near a knowledgeable person in coding and I just happen to be the person with most knowledge regarding this subject hence the reason why I get to look for help.

A while back I Frankensteined together a google script to put a time stamp on a page that would show last revision date and published date. However, recently I've noticed a "Deprecated" message on two lines. I struggled quite a bit to make the current script work so I'm here for some guidance.

```
function doGet(e){
  var app= UiApp.createApplication();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  var updated = Utilities.formatDate(page.getLastUpdated(), "America/Chicago", "EEE, d MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a '('z')'");
  var published = Utilities.formatDate(page.getDatePublished(), "America/Chicago", "EEE, d MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a '('z')'");
  app.add(app.createHTML('Last revision: ' + updated));
  app.add(app.createHTML('Published: ' + published));
  return app;
}
```

This is the current code and here is the error message I'm getting

> UiApp API is deprecated.
>   File: Code Line: 2
>   The API has been marked as deprecated which means that the feature should be avoided and may be removed in the future. Consider using an alternative solution.
>
> UiInstance API is deprecated.
>   File: Code Line: 6
>   The API has been marked as deprecated which means that the feature should be avoided and may be removed in the future. Consider using an alternative solution.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I will keep on doing some research on my side to hopefully better understand this deprecated APIs

Comment: Hey @linkarmy09 and welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be easier to help you if you can provide more context for your problem. It looks like you are using some kind of JavaScript framework, but without us knowing which one it is really hard to help you.

It would also be very helpful if you could formulate a question for which you are looking for an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough to answer the framework question you are asking. This code is being used within a google site if that helps.

I am well aware that I might not get the answer I'm looking for due to my lack of knowledge on this subject but I will try my best.

The way I understand it from the error message is that the "UiApp" and "UiInstance" are no longer (or will soon no longer) be usable or available.  The error message is asking me to replace it  and this is where the issue is, what to replace them with or for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some perusing of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service it would seem like this is the way to do it. This is untested code.

```
function doGet(e){
  var app= HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
  var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
  var updated = Utilities.formatDate(page.getLastUpdated(), "America/Chicago", "EEE, d MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a '('z')'");
  var published = Utilities.formatDate(page.getDatePublished(), "America/Chicago", "EEE, d MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a '('z')'");
  app.append('Last revision: ' + updated);
  app.append('Published: ' + published);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Tested your code. No longer getting the Deprecated error message but now im getting a different error  "ReferenceError: "HTMLService" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: @linkarmy09 Sorry, I had a typo it's supposed to be `HtmlService`

Comment: sorry for the delay I was out of office for a couple of days. You are right deiga after i corrected the error the script seems to be working correctly.